# Unity3d how the surface is engraved

Tags: unity-game-engine

how do I do the mechanics found in this game? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HeroGames.WoodShop

I want to divide the surface with a certain precision.

Answer (score 0):

One relatively straightforward approach would be to:

1. Have a mesh cylinder with a rather big number of sequences. (Ensure it's marked for write access, and that the normals are calcuated at a properly high smoothing angle value.)

[image]

2. When carving at a given point along its length, cast a hypothetical box forward into the mesh and grab all vertex points in it (or grab the points closest to the length position). You need [meshFilter -> mesh -> vertices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) for this.

[image]

3. Bring all those points closer to center, as much as defined by your carving knife forward position. Lerp nearby points if wanted to make the result curvier.
4. Recalculate the mesh. To get a smoother normals, use [this script](https://schemingdeveloper.com/2017/03/26/better-method-recalculate-normals-unity-part-2/) (in my experience the normals still won't look perfect, though).

Not sure if this is the best approach, but maybe it's workable for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this very complicated... Can you explain in more detail?